# X axis scaling with matlab plotting

Tags: matlab, plot

My data is sparse therefore when I plot my graph I get the following result
[image]

As you can see the first x axis tick starts at 500(s), but most of my data is around 30(s). Can I change the scaling of the x axis?

Comment: you can use `semilogx` instead of `plot` to make the x axis logarithmic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
X = [1 3 6 10 25 30 235 678 1248];
Y = [0.4 0.45 0.5 0.55 0.6 0.65 0.7 0.8 0.9];
plot(X,Y,'-b.')
figure
semilogx(X,Y,'-b.')
```

I see the following output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display data from 0 to 30s only you can either plot only those like this:

```
idcs=Xdata <30; %# find indices where X is less than 30s
plot(Xdata(idcs),Ydata(idcs),'b'); %#plot only these data.
```

or you can just express `XLim`its on the figure.

```
plot(Xdata,Ydata,'b'); %# plot everything
set(gca,XLim,[0 30]);  %# limit display on X axis
```

Comment: I don't want 0-30 only, I want all of the data to be displayed.